# How to ask forgiveness when you wish something bad?

Tags: dua, forgiveness

Well now we are in a very critical situation because of corona. All the educational institutions are closed. I am also a student.I wished corona to never end. Because if corona ends I have to go to school. I know it's a really stupid thing to do.I am extremely guilty of it. But never wished anyone's death. I swear to God I haven't wished anyone's death. I just wished people to get infected then recover from it. I know I should have never asked this.
How can I ask forgiveness from Allah?
Will Allah forgive me because of this?..... please answer me for God's sake..

Answer (score 0):

I’ve wished so too, and other people I know also. I don’t think of it as haram because, just like you we didnt wish for anyone to die, just that the pandemic continues but it still sounds wrong I know. However you know yourself that you don’t want anyone to die but maybe it’s still a sin that you wanted people to get infected and recover, I don’t know, but you could always pray for forgiveness either way and if you want a more accurate answer rather consult a scholar.

Answer (score 0):

Don't lose hope in Allah's mercy.
Quran (39:53) ( Tell them O Prophet,"My servants who have been committed excesses against themselves (committed sins) do not lose hope in Allah's mercy. Surely Allah forgives all sins (with repentance). He is the most forgiving most merciful.